# How to replace an empty cell in formula with last numbered cell

Tags: vba, excel

Working on a budget worksheet. I am trying to get the cell to keep looking up the column for one part of the formula if the previous cell is blank.

I currently have the formula to give a blank cell in the 'Remaining' column (E) if the 'Budgeted' column (C) is blank, as seen here
[Budget clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUHqM.jpg)

The issue comes when trying to get a number in the 'Remaining' column when the previous cell above is blank. I would like it to keep looking up the column until it finds a number, then use that number in the equation.
So in the picture, for Expense 5 (A9) I would like it to take cell E6-C9.
And then repeat the formula down the column.

I would like to copy the formula down the column since filled and unfilled cells will change from month to month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell E9

```
=IF(C9>0,$C$3-SUM(C$5:C9),"")
```

I think this will serve the same purpose as calculating E6 - C9 (i.e. calculating how much of the budget is remaining), but it's simpler code.

You should be able to copy it from E5 to the bottom of your table using regular copy-and-paste.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you! You did have one typo though, it should be =IF(C9>0,$C$3-SUM(C$5:C9),""). Changing the C2 cell to C3.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks.